# Tycho cannot connect to Eclipse p2 repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I'm trying to setup Tycho so I can use my Maven dependencies in an Eclipse-Plugin project. In all the documentation and online tutorials I found so for you have to add the eclipse p2 repository to your maven pom.xml at some point (otherwise the build will fail).

So I included the following configuration in my parent pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eclipse-luna</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

However the build still fails:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] No explicit target runtime environment configuration. Build is platform dependent.
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: Plugin123:Plugin123:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\workspaces\Plugin\pom.xml
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'eclipse-luna' from location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/: Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/content.xml: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'eclipse-luna' from location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'eclipse-luna' from location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.loadMetadataRepository(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.gatherExternalInstallableUnits(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.manager.ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(P2DependencyResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/content.xml
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteRepositoryCacheManager.createCache(RemoteRepositoryCacheManager.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.loadMetadataRepository(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:298)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

All I could found while googeling was to start Eclipse with -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true which didn't fixed the problem for me. For some reason I can't even reach http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/content.xml with my web browser. I also tried to find a mirror of the repository, but I just found tutorials on how to create your own mirros (which also doesn't worked for me).

Does anyone now whats going on here?

Comment: Are you behind an HTTP proxy?

Comment: Yes I am. I edited the Eclipse network settings to use the proxy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your proxy configuration is not correct. Tycho uses proxy configuration that are configured for Maven. Check the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) for how to configure a proxy for the Maven build.

Tycho cannot use the Eclipse configuration because it is a command line build tool that runs independent of the Eclipse workspace.

Comment: I figured it was proxy issue, but I was trying to pass the proxy on command line `http_proxy=<myserver:port> mvn clean verify` but it seems maven was not honoring it. The moment i put it on maven settings.xml, this above issue got resolved. Hope this helps someone.